# Formatting the title page of a book

Tags: titles, books, book-design, author

I am writing a book, and was wondering how to make the title page similar to the following example, without the reference number `1`

Since I have the title page in a separate tex file like the different book chapters, I prefer not to manually enter the page definitions after `\begin{document}`.

Thank you for any idea you can provide.

```
\documentclass{extbook}

\title{Book Title}

\author{Author
    \thanks{
        \begin{center}
            Department\\
            \medskip
            University\\
            State
        \end{center}
}}

\date{}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\tanks{}` is for make a footnote , so only have sense in author armuent if  you want the reference to this footnote, not normal text at bottom . The orthodox way to do custom title pagesis `\begin{titlepage}   whatever \end{titlepage}` where you are who makes the title, i.e., what is  "whatever" and how it should look is completely up to you.

Comment: @Fran: Even between `\begin{titlepage}   \end{titlepage}`, no regular text can be placed at the bottom of the title page.

Comment: Of course that it can be placed. See the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\tanks{}` should not be used except if you want a footnote using `\maketitle`.

To make a custom title you must redefine `\maketitle`, or simpler, use a `titlepage` environment. Unlike `\maketitle`, the environment do not make any automatic content, nor have any predefined format, excepting that also start and end a page without number, so what is the content, and how is should formatted, is up to you.

As in the main text, you can push some text to touch the bottom margin simply  adding `\vfill`, before  that is,  a `v`ertical space that `fill` the rest of the page.

So a basic content of `titlepage` environment could be some like:

```
\centering 
Book Title \par   
Author \par 
\vfill Departament ...
```

Note that define `\title`, `\author` and `\date` are not required at all for the  `titlepage`. You can just type the text. However, for a more rich format (with many commands for setting fonts, spaces, colors, ornaments, etc.) it could be more convenient edit these commands at the beginning of the preamble, as well as convenience some custo macro as `\institute`, and then reuse this information in `titlepage` automatically, instead of having to rummage and edit that contents between somewhat convoluted code. Unfortunately, it is a bit tricky retrieve  `\title`, `\author` and `\date` information excepting using \maketitle, but this is a example of how it can be done:

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{extbook}

\title{Book Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\newcommand\institute{%
Department of Something\par
University of Nowhere\par
State of Art} 

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the MWE
\usepackage{pgfornament} % just because I want ornaments ;)

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 

\begin{titlepage}
\makeatletter
\centering  
{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\@title} \bigskip\par
{\Large\bfseries\@author} \bigskip\par
\@date
\makeatother
\vfill
\pgfornament[width=.35\linewidth]{84}\bigskip\par
\large\institute
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}
    First document. This is a simple example
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My title is long, and broken into multiple lines that seem to be very close to each other. I was wondering how to increase the interline spacing between the different lines of the title.
Besides, what does the `[openany]` argument mean for `\documentclass`?

Comment: @AEW The `openany` option is to start chapter in odd or even pages to avoid blank pages in the example (good for read a pdf, bad to print a formal book).

Comment: @AEW There are several ways to fix the interline spacing. One is just type a title with manual line breaks as like  `Book \\[.5em] Long \\[.5em] Title` and other could be some like  `{...\baselineskip2em\@title\par}` for automatic line breaks. Do not forget the `\par` (= blank line) after `\@title` but **inside** the `{...} ` group or your will notice that nothing change.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.